# Webpack Permission denied

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, webpack

When I do a simple PUSH IN my azure remote inside LOG of deployment center I've a 'FAILED' status with this error:

> sh: 1: webpack: Permission denied nodeapi@1.0.0 build
>   /tmp/8d76a8f24a2e399 npm ERR! file sh NODE_ENV=production webpack
>   --config ./webpack.production.config.js npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR! nodeapi@1.0.0
>   build: `NODE_ENV=production webpack --config
>   ./webpack.production.config.js` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm ERR!  npm
>   ERR! Failed at the nodeapi@1.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2019-11-16T12_19_06_372Z-debug.log npm WARN
>   nodeapi@1.0.0 No repository field.\n\nsh: 1: webpack: Permission
>   denied\nnpm ERR! file sh\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno
>   ENOENT\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\nnpm ERR! nodeapi@1.0.0 build:
>   `NODE_ENV=production webpack --config
>   ./webpack.production.config.js`\nnpm ERR! spawn ENOENT\nnpm ERR! \nnpm
>   ERR! Failed at the nodeapi@1.0.0 build script.\nnpm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2019-11-16T12_19_06_372Z-debug.log\n/opt/Kudu/KuduConsole/Scripts/starter.sh
>   oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform
>   nodejs --platform-version 8.9 -i /tmp/8d76a8f24a2e399 -p
>   compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log

Comment: hi, anything new on that?